# Testing ActiveRecord associations with Shoulda in non-Rails app

Tags: activerecord, rspec, sinatra, shoulda

App: Sinatra + ActiveRecord
Trying to test association existence using best practices.
I really like the Shoulda syntax:

```
    describe Bar do
      it { should belong_to(:foo) }
    end
```

However, RSpec cannot seem to find the `belong_to` method.

```
    1) ResOutcome 
       Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:foo) }
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000103ac6760>
       # ./spec/models/bar_spec.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any hints?
Does Shoulda association testing only work in Rails apps (with rspec-rails)?
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers mention, this happens because `shoulda-matchers` is being included before your ActiveRecord connection is established, at least on Sinatra.

In your Gemfile, be sure to add `require: false`, like so:

```
gem "shoulda-matchers", "~> 2.4.0", require: false
```

This prevents the app from automatically requiring the gem before anything else has been done.

Then in your `spec/spec_helper.rb`, first require your app (where `active_record` is presumably included and the connection is established), and then later in the file, manually require `shoulda-matchers`. For example:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../the_app_itself'
require 'shoulda-matchers'
```

Now you can use the matchers in your specs as usual:

```
describe LouieGeetoo do
  it { should have_many(:video_games) }
end
```

Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `shoulda-matchers` gem to your Gemfile?
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

---

**Update:**

Add `require 'shoulda/matchers` to your `spec_helper.rb` configuration.

Comment: I have another idea, try `require 'shoulda/matchers'` in `spec_helper.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, although I'm not using RSpec.  Still using Sinatra and ActiveRecord though.

In my case, I needed to change my test classes from inheriting from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` to inheriting from `Test::Unit::TestCase`.

I wasn't using the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` functionality anyway, so it worked OK.  I realize this isn't really your use case, but maybe it points you in the right direction and helps someone else who is using `Test::Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and were working in a non-Rails app.

Our issue turned out to be because we had tried to require 'shoulda-matchers' before we had actually required our app, which meant that the gem was looking for ActiveRecord::Base and couldn't find it.

We fixed the problem by requiring the app first and then requiring 'shoulda-matchers' afterwards. Stupid.